# Error message when updating applications in Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

I have a dual boot system which has Windows 7 and Kubuntu 20.10. When I was trying to update all installed applications in the Kubuntu OS, I got this error message:

***Package failed to install Error while installing package: installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1***

What does the error mean? Is there any problem with my installed Kubuntu 20.10 OS? Please help me fix this issue.

The screenshot image of the result after running the commands suggested by @user535733 in a comment:

[image]

Comment: okay, I'll try it soon @user535733

Comment: @user535733 I've done run the commands u suggested before, and put the screenshot on my question above, so.. what do u think?